# Custom order status count for WooCommerce dashboard status widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change my default status in WooCommerce Admin Dashboard widget to custom status from the plugin order status manager.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT2C4.jpg

**First step**
So I found the `status_widget_order_rows` hook code  in the docs from WooCommerce  and addded this to my functions.php, i replaced all the default statuses to 
my custom statuses `'needs changes' = wc-change` and `'waiting for approval' = wc-waiting`. I saved it but nothing happened.

**Second step**
I thought that when i remove the hook and replace it with mine custom hook, it will be shown, but this didn't happen. 

**Third afford**
I thought that when i add manually the status in mine functions.php , and then hook to the status it will show, but that didn't either.

```
function custom_remove_status_widget_order_rows() {
    remove_action('WC_Admin_Dashboard', 'status_widget_order_rows' );
    add_action('WC_Admin_Dashboard', 'custom_status_widget_order_rows', 10, 2);}

function custom_status_widget_order_rows() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $change_count    = 0;
    $waiting_count = 0;

    foreach ( wc_get_order_types( 'order-count' ) as $type ) {
        $counts           = (array) wp_count_posts( $type );
        $change_count    += isset( $counts['wc-change'] ) ? $counts['wc-change'] : 0;
        $waiting_count   += isset( $counts['wc-waiting'] ) ? $counts['wc-waiting'] : 0;
    }
    ?>
    <li class="waiting-orders">
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'edit.php?post_status=wc-waiting&post_type=shop_order' ); ?>">
            <?php
                /* translators: %s: order count */
                printf(
                    _n( '<strong>%s order</strong> waiting to be approved', '<strong>%s orders</strong> awaiting waiting', $waiting_count, 'woocommerce' ),
                    $waiting_count
                );
            ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="change-orders">
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'edit.php?post_status=wc-change&post_type=shop_order' ); ?>">
            <?php
                /* translators: %s: order count */
                printf(
                    _n( '<strong>%s order</strong> needs changes', '<strong>%s orders</strong> are changed', $change_count, 'woocommerce' ),
                    $rejected_count
                );
            ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php
}?>
```

**Last**
Somehow i need to load first the statuses from the plugin and then override the default woocommerce class, and then add rows.

Here is the link to the plugin -> docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-manager/

But i am beginner php, so i hope someone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WC_Admin_Dashboard is not a hook.

You should use woocommerce_after_dashboard_status_widget.